# Compile a matlab m-file into a usable C-function

Tags: cuda, mex, matlab

Hey there,
is there a way to compile (or better to say: 'translate') a matlab m-function into a C-function so that I can use it in the CUDA kernel of my mex file?
thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[MATLAB Coder](http://www.mathworks.com/products/matlab-coder/?s_cid=global_nav) will generate C code for mex files. I do not yet have a copy to evaluate, so I can't speak with any authority about the quality and nature of the generated code.

However, if I had to guess, I'd say the generated code would likely require a lot of massaging to get it working on your GPU. You may have better luck with a product like [Jacket](http://www.accelereyes.com/products/jacket), depending on what you're doing.

Comment: +1 to that.   It's one thing to generate C code; it's another thing _entirely_ to generate a useful CUDA kernel.  The constraints on what can usefully be put in a CUDA kernal are vastly different than what can be run on a generic CPU.

Comment: OKay thanks, but unfortunatly I can't get a trial version as student to try if that would work well to support my GPU-kernel :(

Answer (score 1):

You can call a matlab (m or mex) function from C / fortran using [this](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/apiref/mexcallmatlab.html) function call. You could then interface that with along with your CUDA kernel.

However it may not be the most efficient way to do things. You could write your own C code for the m file that you have or look it up on matlab central if any one else has done it.

Comment: I already know that but as I understand it so far, the function will than be ran on the CPU instead of GPU, because matlab runs on the CPU

Comment: Then I don't understand what you are asking. COuld you elobarate more on that ?

Comment: I want to pass a function handle when calling my mex-function to it. The function handle is supposed to be evaluated on the GPU (i.e. in the kernel function) for thousands of different parameters. That's what I want to parallelize! When I use mexCallMATLAB to call matlab-function 'feval' to evaluate the function handle from within the C-code, this will evaluate the function handle on the CPU and not on the GPU and thus, the parallelization is senseless.

Comment: You can not do that without writing your own cuda code. Not just for the C part, but also for the m code part. You can not pass function handles into cuda.

Answer (score 1):

The C function will call eventually set-up device variables and call a CUDA kernel?

I originally wanted to try this for a project because I thought this method would be easier than converting all of my MATLAB code to C first, but I ended up doing that anyway.

There are some user created MATLAB scripts to help provide this functionality, but since they aren't from the Mathworks you'll have to use them at your own risk. I tried them and never found anything malicious, but you never know. I couldn't get them to work with my project due to its specific complications but it should work for simpler tasks.

1) NvMEX: This is directly from Nvidia. http://developer.stage.nvidia.com/matlab-cuda
http://www.mathworks.com/discovery/matlab-gpu.html

2) CUDA MEX: This is from a user. http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/25314-cuda-mex

Comment: OKay thanks I'll have a look at those links now. I would prefer not to have to write the code into C directly. Not because it's too much work for me, but rather for the user. I would like to compile the mex-file ONCE into a user-friendly function, so that the user can easily call the function on every functionhandle of matlab he wants to! Edit: The two links you posted don't belong to the problem directly. The just state about how to compile a mex file including CUDA (so this is the basic of every cuda-mex application on not directly related to my problem ;))

Answer (score 1):

This is not really a direct answer to your question, but if your goal is simply to have your MATLAB code run on the GPU, then you may find that if you have access to [Parallel Computing Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/products/parallel-computing/), you can use [GPUArrays](http://www.mathworks.com/discovery/matlab-gpu.html) with [arrayfun](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/distcomp/bsic4n4-1.html). For example, if the function you wish to evaluate across many points looks like this:

```
function y = myFcn( x )
y = 1;
for ii = 1:10
  y = sin(x * y);
end
```

Then you could call this on the GPU like so:

```
gx = gpuArray( rand(1000) );
gy = arrayfun( @myFcn, gx );
```